# Schedule offline db2 database backup on Windows

Tags: database, command-line, db2, scheduled-tasks

I only have access to the command line processor and I would like to set up a backup policy to do an offline backup once a day of a db2 database.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

To do a single offline backup I know the code is

```
BACKUP DATABASE <database> TO <“drive/location”> <params>
```

However I can not figure out how to schedule this

Comment: Care to mention the DB2 version?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LUW, you can:

- In Windows, create a task in the Taks Schedule with the backup command. - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7
- In linux, put the command in the crontab of a user with the privileges to execute the backup. Remember to load the db2 instance profile.
- You can configure automatic backups in any OS - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0052291.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows OS, then you create a new task and on the action tab:

`Action:` Start a program

`Program/script:` ***"D:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2cmd.exe"*** (path there the db2cmd.exe is located)

`Add arguments (optional):` /**c /w /i db2 backup database DBNAME to X:\Backup COMPRESS WITHOUT PROMPTING**

`Start in (optional):` blank

The command above will backup database DBNAME to X:\Backup folder compressing the DB.